# How to add log to Syslog while creating new log file by log4j?

Tags: java, log4j, syslog

i want to add log into systems event log when:-

1.create new log file
2.create backup of file,when maximum size reached.
3.create a log file when open and close the log.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled the syslog in your Linux machine you can configure log4j.properties like below

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, SYSLOG

log4j.appender.SYSLOG=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.SyslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Facility=Local3
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.Header=true
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.ConversionPattern=java %d{ISO8601} %p %t %c{0}.%M - %m%n
```